# Python Tkinter - How to place the input from an entry using entry.get()

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have an entry named "Username".

```
username = Entry()
username.place(x = 10, y = 50)
```

and a submit button

```
submit = Button(text="Submit", command=getInfo)
submit.place(x = 150, y = 48)
```

It calls a getInfo function

```
def getInfo():
 user = username.get()
```

I'd like to place user as a label. I can print it just fine, the text shows up in the console. When I try to place, I get an error.

```
File "tk.py", line 8, in getInfo
user.place(x = 150, y = 90)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'place'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says: `user` is a string. You know it's a string, because you got it from an `Entry` widget using `get()`, which returns a string. You need to make a new widget to hold this string, and place that.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, `user` is a string and not a widget. Hence it doesn't have a place method like `username` and `submit`. You want to stick it into a label and then place the label.